# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843 while deploying in Weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I am trying to perform a select operation on my oracle db. I have kept my queries in a property file in my application which is as follows:

```sql
SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM EMPLOYEETABLE WHERE
JOINING_DATETIME >= ?
```

The `JOINING_DATETIME` is a timestamp column in oracle db and its value looks like `04-03-20 07:12:27.150000000 PM`

I am supplying the value for `JOINING_DATETIME` as a String from my application like `04-03-20 05:41:52 PM` and it works very well and do the necessary as expected while running in Tomcat servers.

But the problem is when the same has been deployed into Weblogic application I'm getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Could someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `string` to `timestamp` using the proper format in your query as follows:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE
  FROM EMPLOYEETABLE
 WHERE JOINING_DATETIME >= TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'DD-MM-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM');
```

**Update**:

Regarding your doubt of `AM/PM`:

```
SQL> select TO_TIMESTAMP('04-03-20 07:12:27.150000000 PM','DD-MM-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') from dual;
TO_TIMESTAMP('04-03-2007:12:27.150000000PM','DD-MM-RRHH:MI:SS.FFAM')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-MAR-20 07.12.27.150000000 PM

SQL> select TO_TIMESTAMP('04-03-20 07:12:27.150000000 AM','DD-MM-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP('04-03-2007:12:27.150000000AM','DD-MM-RRHH:MI:SS.FFAM')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-MAR-20 07.12.27.150000000 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any format available for mentioning AM/PM. Because it comes dynamically. Also I executed as you mentioned
JOINING_DATETIME >= to_timestamp('04-03-20 05:41:52 AM','DD-MM-RR HH:MI:SS FFFFFFFFF AM') 
But I am getting 
ORA-01810: format code appears twice
01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"

Comment: See the update section!! There is no need to worry. If you pass PM in your string it will take PM. AM is just to indicate that it can be AM/PM in the actual string.
I have updated the answer to include only `FF` instead of 9 `F`

Comment: Thanks Tejash for your update. I checked it by executing in db and it works. But I need to test my application once for this. I have a doubt like why the later query worked fine in tomcat but not in weblogic ?

Comment: It depends on the NLS setting of the sessions initiated by the different tools/clients. You must read about the NLS and you should not use string. It is not recommended at all. You must convert the string to timestamp and use it in the query so that it is executed from anywhere (independent of NLS setting of the session)

Comment: Thanks again Tejash. I have one more question like, if I do to_timestamp in all my queries instead of changing my code for not passing as a string. Will this result as a costly operation in means of performance ?

Answer (score 3):

Supply the value for `JOINING_DATETIME` as a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of a String.